# c# mocking IFormFile CopyToAsync() method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, stream, moq

I am working on a unit test for an async function that converts a list of IFormFile to a list of my own arbitrary database file classes.

The method that converts the file data to a byte array is:

```
internal async Task<List<File>> ConvertFormFilesToFiles(ICollection<IFormFile> formFiles)
{
    var file = new File
    {
        InsertDateTime = DateTime.Now,
        LastChangeDateTime = DateTime.Now
    };
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream, CancellationToken.None);
            file.FileData = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

The function receives an ICollection of IFormFiles so it is mockable.

For now I have test code like this:

```
//Arrange
var fileConverter = new FilesConverter();
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("Files/uploadme.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var newMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        FormFileMock.Setup(f => f.CopyToAsync(newMemoryStream, CancellationToken.None)).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
        // some other setups

        //Act
        var result = await fileConverter.ConvertFormFilesToFiles(new List<IFormFile> { FormFileMock.Object });
        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Any());
    }
}
```

The newMemoryStream variable is created because the function calls the CopyToAsync method with a new and empty memorystream (I'm not sure if this is necessary).

The problem is that the **await formFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream, CancellationToken.None)** doesn't copy any data to the memoryStream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I combined the answers of @Nkosi and @nvoigt. As @nvoigt pointed out: access to a real file should really not be in a "unit" test. So I replaced the file with a byte array like so:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(new byte[]{1,2,3,4}))
```

Instead of a complete file.

And I implemented the .callback on the mocked object as suggested by @Nkosi

```
FormFileMock.Setup(f => f.CopyToAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>(), CancellationToken.None))
    .Callback<Stream, CancellationToken>((stream, token) =>
    {
        // with memoryStream being the stream from inside the using statement
        memoryStream.CopyTo(stream);
    }).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 11):

I know this might be unpopular because using a mock framework is totally "in" these days, but why not simply leave the framework be framework and go the simple, easy way? You can create a `FormFile` without any mocking. Just the real deal:

```
var fileConverter = new FilesConverter(FilesConverterLoggerMock.Object, FileDataMock.Object);

// access to a real file should really not be in a "unit" test, but anyway: 
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("Files/uploadme.txt"))
{
  // create a REAL form file
  var formFile = new FormFile(stream , 0, stream.Length, "name", "filename");

  //Act
  var result = await fileConverter.ConvertFormFilesToFiles(new List<IFormFile> { formFile });

  //Assert
  Assert.IsTrue(result.Any());
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. It removes all the complexity of setting up the mock. clean, simple, and gets the job done.

Comment: This works but I combined this answer with @Nkosi his answer.

Answer (score 8):

> The problem is that the `await formFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream, CancellationToken.None)` doesn't copy any data to the `memoryStream`.

According to your setup. Nothing will actually be copied.

You just setup the call to return as completed. No actual functionality was implemented.

You'll need to add a `Callback` to perform some desired functionality before returning the task.

```
FormFileMock
    .Setup(_ => _.CopyToAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>(), CancellationToken.None))
    .Callback<Stream, CancellationToken>((stream, token) => {
        //memory stream in this scope is the one that was populated
        //when you called **fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);** in the test
        memoryStream.CopyTo(stream);
    }) 
    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

Comment: This works but I combined this answer with @nvoigt his answer.

Comment: Once it solves your problem. I would suggest you accept one of them. His was better IMHO