# How to mock fake file size in bytes array in unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

Here I have code which copies the document to specific loacation for that I have code which creates fake file as below.

```
private static Mock<IFormFile> GetMockFormFile()
{
      var fileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();
      var fileStreamProviderMock = new Mock<IFileStreamProvider>();
      var contentTypes = "text/plain";
      var content = "Fake File";
      var fileName = "Test.txt";
      var disk = new MemoryStream();
      var writers = new StreamWriter(disk);
      writers.Write(content);
      writers.Flush();
      disk.Position = 0;
      fileMock.Setup(_ => _.OpenReadStream()).Returns(disk);
      fileMock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(fileName);
      fileMock.Setup(_ => _.Length).Returns(disk.Length);
      fileMock.Setup(_ => _.ContentType).Returns(contentTypes);
      fileMock.Setup(_ => _.ContentDisposition).Returns($"form-data;name='file';filename ='{fileName}'");
      fileStreamProviderMock.Setup(_ => _.Create(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(disk);
      fileStreamProviderMock.Setup(_ => _.Open(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(disk);
      fileMock.Setup(_ => _.CopyToAsync(disk, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
      fileMock.Verify();
      return fileMock;
}
```

I am passing this fake file to controller like

```
[Fact]
public async sample()
{
    var formFile = GetMockFormFile();
    var file = formFile.Object;
    var SavedFile = new AttachmentMetadata
    {
        Id = 4231,
        DocumentName = file.FileName,
        DocumentType = file.ContentType,
        CreatedDateTime = dateTime,
        ModifiedDateTime = dateTime
    };
    var viewModel = new AttachmentViewModel()
    {
        File = new List<IFormFile> { file }
    };

    await controller.AddAttachment(viewModel);
    fileStreamProviderMock.Verify(_ => _.Create(@"C:\TestFolder\Test.txt"));
    formFile.Verify(_ => _.CopyToAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));
}
```

and inside my controller i have some code as like

```
foreach (var file in model.File)
  {
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
       {
            file.CopyTo(ms);
            fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
       } 
  ----
  ----
}
```

which should return the fileBytes something except 0, currently I am getting fileBytes as 0 which cause issues in further code execution.
So is there any other way where I can mock this fake bytes size?

Comment: You mock `CopyToAsync` but call the synchronous `CoptyTo`. Why? Also you can use a callback to access the passed stream and populate it with what ever data you want

Comment: Can you provide more details so I can reproduce this issue. The currently shown code is incomplete. So all I can do for now is guess or make inconclusive assumptions about your interfaces.

Comment: Take a look here for how to setup `CopyToAsync` on `IFormFile` https://stackoverflow.com/a/47309469/5233410

Comment: Don't call `fileMock.Verify();` right after setup.